# Cannot determine the size of graphic

Tags: graphics, positioning

I know this question asked here before, and I've seen all your answer but it didn't  work with me

just `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{first.png}`work, but if I do that then I can't control on the position of graph, so could you help ?

Comment: If you are using latex rather than pdflatex then you need to tell it the size of the figure (as it can not read the png file to discover it). If you use pdflatex this is not needed as it can read png files.  I do not understand your last comment as these size keys have no connection with commands you use to control the position of the figure.

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate as the earlier one (it even has exactly the same title) However if you are having a problem with _positioning_ the image, please feel free to ask a new question on that, preferably with some example code that shows the problem.

Comment: how i cant tell it the size of the figure ?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand that last comment. If you are using `pdflatex` then you can use `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{first.png}` but if you are using latex you must use `natheight` and `natwidth` to tell latex the size of the image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please tell us how you are compiling your tex file.

Comment: I'm usin TeXnic center

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, i use latex and i use `natheight` but it didn't work !

Comment: did you set it to the correct value, in your question you have specified that the image is 642 postscript points high before scaling, if that is not accurate latex will get confused. In the duplicate question answer are some tools that you can use to determine this exactly, automatically

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{first.png}
 \label{fig:first}
\end{figure}`

I did it and there is no error, but now How i can controlling position of the graph ?

Comment: The position is controled by TeX according to an algorithm for floating objects. If you put your image within a `figure`environment then is a floating.

Comment: Your questions are totally confusing. The question about image size is a duplicate, and you hint you have  a problem with float placement but unless you say what that problem is (in a new question) no one will be able to guess what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 
Finally it's work !!

Comment: sorry but i was very confusing @DavidCarlisle

Comment: :-) glad you got it working, welcome to the site:-)